# How to configure Ribbon/Hystrix per route or per endpoint using Zuul Proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I have an `ft-admin` microservive which exposes 2 endpoints `app-config` and `app-analytic`. In my `@EnableZuulProxy` gateway project, I can define the routing rules and specify other configurations for Ribbon and Hystrix on microservice-level using the `serviceId` as following.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    admin-services:
      path: /admin/**
      serviceId: ft-admin
      stripPrefix: true

ft-admin:
  ribbon:
    ActiveConnectionsLimit: 2

hystrix:
  command:
    ft-admin:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 10000
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to bring the above configurations down to endpoint-level for each `app-config` and `app-analytic` individually. The goal is to be able to give a different setting for each endpoint as following.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    app-config-endpoint:
      path: /app-config/**
      serviceId: ft-admin
      stripPrefix: false
    app-analytic-endpoint:
      path: /app-analytic/**
      serviceId: ft-admin
      stripPrefix: false

app-config-endpoint:
  ribbon:
    ActiveConnectionsLimit: 5
app-analytic-endpoint:
  ribbon:
    ActiveConnectionsLimit: 2

...
```

When I run my gateway project in Debug mode with `ft-admin.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit: 2`, I can see the following lines in the log.

```
c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Property changed: 'ft-admin.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit = 2'
c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: ft-admin.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use it's current value:2
```

However, when I run my project with `app-config-endpoint.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit: 5`, I see the following lines.

```
c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Property changed: 'ft-admin.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit = -2147483648'
c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Flipping property: ft-admin.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647
```

I've tried to search through a ton of posts but it seems like the configurations always stop at the microservice-level. The endpoint/route level configurations are completely ignore.

I'd be very grateful if you could point me in the right direction or tell me your story if you've tried this before.

Comment: The granularity is per route. So if you split it like /admin/config/** etc, each could have it's own.

Comment: @spencergibb: Do you mean the configuration would work if I use `app-config-endpoint` to configure Ribbon? In the documentation, they specifically mentioned `<clientName>.ribbon`. I'm assuming `clientName` is `serviceId` which is used to register with Eureka.

Comment: in zuul it is per route. so it is the route id, so yes `app-config-endpoint`.

Comment: @spencergibb: I tested setting `ft-admin.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit` to 2 in my `application.yml` and I can see `c.netflix.config.ChainedDynamicProperty  : Property changed: 'ft-admin.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit = 2'` being printed on the console in Debug mode. However, when I tried setting per route like `app-config-endpoint.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit`, the log shows `Flipping property: ft-admin.ribbon.ActiveConnectionsLimit to use NEXT property: niws.loadbalancer.availabilityFilteringRule.activeConnectionsLimit = 2147483647`. Configurations per route doesn't work at all.

Comment: I don't know how ribbon uses `ActiveConnectionsLimit`

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/Netflix/ribbon/blob/304e38cf765a1d09ec950502ac62437a05c7eab4/ribbon-loadbalancer/src/main/java/com/netflix/loadbalancer/AvailabilityPredicate.java, they load both properties, using the latter as a default. Put a breakpoint in `AvailabilityPredicate`